# Insert 1 statement based on 3 select statements

Tags: sql, select, sql-insert

I have a table like this:

```
| Name | Parent Id | Pricing Id | Paper Id |
|------------------------------------------|
|      |           |            |          |
```

That I want to insert into. Problem is, the customer doesn't know the ID's, only the values of the name fields from the Parent/Pricing/Paper table:

```
| Name | Parent Id | Pricing Id | Paper Id |
|------------------------------------------|
|Narnia| Movies    | MidTier    | Film     |
|Transf| Movies    | HighTier   | Comic    |
```

`Movies`, `MidTier`/`HighTier` and `Film`/`Comic` would need to be converted to ints... Here's psuedo-query:

```
INSERT INTO products (Name, ParentId, PricingId, PaperId)
    VALUES (
        "Narnia",
        SELECT id FROM categories WHERE Name="Movies",
        SELECT id FROM pricing WHERE Name="MidTier",
        SELECT id FROM papers WHERE Name="Film"
    )
```

Obviously that isn't going to work, but what would be the correct way of doing this?

**EDIT:** Note that efficiency isn't a super high priority as this will be a one time import (of hundreds of thousands of products).

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: @cybork Last sentence before the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these 3 tables cannot be joined together, you can define variables for the different ids

```
DECLARE @categoryId INT,
       @pricingId INT,
       @papersId INT

SELECT @categoryId = id FROM categories WHERE Name="Movies",
SELECT @pricingId = id FROM pricing WHERE Name="MidTier",
SELECT @papersId = id FROM papers WHERE Name="Film"

INSERT INTO products (Name, ParentId, PricingId, PaperId)
VALUES ('Narnia', @categoryId, @pricingId, @paperId)
```

But if you can join these tables and insert values like following generic statement:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (...)
SELECT t2.id, t3.id
FROM tbl2 as t2
INNER JOIN tbl3 as t3 on t3.id = t2.t3_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer these because you can see what exactly will be inserted. Either should work. If performance is a concern, you should check them, but I prefer the cross join because I can see everything in one spot for the values. I'm using a sub-select for Narnia so if we wanted to insert 20 products, we could simply add a union in the sub-select.

```
INSERT INTO products (Name, ParentId, PricingId, PaperId)
    SELECT
        Name.Name,c.ID,prc.ID,ppr.ID
    FROM (
        SELECT 'Narnia' [Name]
    ) [Name]
    CROSS JOIN categories c
    CROSS JOIN pricing prc
    CROSS JOIN papers ppr
    WHERE 
        c.Name='Movies'
    AND prc.Name='MidTier'
    AND ppr.Name='Film'

INSERT INTO products (Name, ParentId, PricingId, PaperId)
    SELECT
        Name.Name,c.ID,prc.ID,ppr.ID
    FROM (
        SELECT 'Narnia' [Name]
    ) [Name]
    LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.Name='Movies'
    LEFT JOIN pricing prc ON prc.Name='MidTier'
    LEFT JOIN papers ppr ON ppr.Name='Film'
```